# Xcode: SQLite in embedded method

Tags: database, xcode, sqlite

I'm dealing here with a new problem. 
I started with the following code:

```
-(IBAction) Login:(id) sender{

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Login= (\"%@\") AND Password = (\"%@\")", Login.text, Password.text];

        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                //Store '1' when a user wants to stay logged 
                **if(logSwitch.on){
                    [self aStayLogged];
                }else{
                    [self aReleaseLogged];
                }**
                Model *model = [Model sharedModel];
                model.paramLogged = Login.text;
                //[self openSecondView:nil];

            } else {
                Status.text = @"Login failed: Please check your ID and Password";
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        }
        sqlite3_close(contactDB);
    }
}

-(void) aStayLogged {

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
            NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE CONTACTS SET LOGGED = '1' WHERE LOGIN = (\"%@\")", Login.text];     
            const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];      
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, update_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        int success = sqlite3_step(statement);
            if (success == SQLITE_ERROR) {
                //NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
                Status.text = @"Update failed";
            }else{
                **Status.text = @"Stay OK";**
            }
        //sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [coffeeName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        //sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 2, coffeeID);

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

Here's the deal: If I link the method 'aStayLogged' as an IBAction to a button, the update is done correctly. But when I embed this method into the 'Login' method, nothing happens!

I check this with the method:

```
-(IBAction) Check{

    sqlite3_stmt *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT LOGIN FROM CONTACTS WHERE LOGGED = '1'"]; 
        const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);

        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

            NSString *loggedField = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];

            Status.text = loggedField;

            [loggedField release];

        }else{

            Status.text = @"Update failed";

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);    

}
```

The funny thing is that the status changes into "Stay OK" which is a confirmation that it should have worked!  Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause of this? Sorry for the long post -  I also happen to ask stupid questions, but this time I really don't see it...

Comment: By the way, the double stars were supposed to put the text in bold...

Comment: And where is "UPDATE ..." SQL?

Comment: Hello Moonlight, it is in the method aStayLogged. ->  NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"UPDATE CONTACTS SET LOGGED = '1' WHERE LOGIN = (\"%@\")", Login.text]; It's when you scroll down in the first block...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm, I think what you used wrong to check with SQLITE_ERROR, because there are many other status code which mate not complete, you better to check on SQLITE_OK or SQLITE_ROW, and if you got this status code, than you're done well.

If you got an error, than use `sqlite3_errmsg` to find out what went wrong. I think there is something with SQLITE_BUSY perhaps or LOCK

Comment: Moonlight, I did what you told me. I used the SQLITE_OK now, and added: NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB)); to check. Then I tried to build via the 'Login' and also 'aStayLogged' as IBAction. For the 'Login' version, I received message: 'Error while creating update statement. 'database is locked'', while for the IBAction:'Error while creating update statement. 'unknown error'' Strange, without the 'Assert', the IBAction used to work. And how can the DB be locked, if the sqlite3_open was successful?

Answer (score 0):

I **suspect** your problem is here:

```
    int success = sqlite3_step(statement);
    if (success == SQLITE_ERROR) {
        //NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to insert into the database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(contactDB));
        Status.text = @"Update failed";
    }else{
        **Status.text = @"Stay OK";**
    }
```

Check the actual result of `sqlite3_step`. You need to keep stepping until it's `SQLITE_DONE`.

Problems like this are a lot easier to diagnose if you check SQLite's results after every call, rather than just chaining ifs together.

Comment: Steven, you suggest that an IF statement testing the 'SQLITE_ERROR' may not be the proper way for checking the success of the statement execution; however, I didn't find another way to do it. Could you explain me how it can be done, or provide me a source where I can find an answer to this question? Thanks

Comment: It isn't that it's wrong, it's that in checking for equality against a specific constant you're discarding what else it might be. For this specific issue, I'd put a breakpoint on the Stay OK line and check its value. If it's SQLITE_ROW, you need to step again. If it's `SQLITE_DONE` (or possibly `SQLITE_OK`? I can't remember.), you're done. If it's anything else, it's an error. That's more than just `SQLITE_ERROR`.

Comment: You might want to look into using fmdb instead of SQLite directly. It's a fairly minimal Cocoa wrapper for SQLite. I've used SQLite directly for years, and I've been considering switching over.

Comment: Thanks, what you say seems right and I tried to debug your way using the SQLITE_OK. Although I didn't finish my code yet, it seems as if I want to update something while the Database is locked because I used the SELECT statement already. Regarding the FMDB, I looked it up on the net and it seems very interesting. However, since I haven't got the experience yet that you have obtained during the years, I will stick to the standard SQLite code first and study it to the bottom. Perhaps afterwards I will look into the wrapper if it actually facilitates work. Thanks for your help!